# arc4random() gives negative Number in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random

Sometime **`arc4random()`** gives negative number also in objective C.

My code is as follow:

Try 1:

```
long ii = arc4random();
```

Try 2:

```
int i = arc4random();
```

**How can I only get positivite random number?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's always positive as it returns an unsigned 32-bit integer ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)):

```
u_int32_t arc4random(void);
```

You are treating it as a signed integer, which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Then treat it as unsigned integer?

Comment: @user2526811 Yes; store it in a `unsigned` or `NSUInteger` and ensure you use format `%u` with `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, amongst other things.

Comment: Yes; but it really depends on what you are doing with the value, just as much as what type you store it in.  However the compiler will at least be able to warn you of misuse if you use the right type.

Comment: `unsigned int ii = arc4random();` is not giving positive always. please check it

Comment: @user2526811 Haven't we gone through all this already?  See the other comments on this answer.

Comment: still I am not getting you

Comment: Well an `unsigned int` cannot even hold a negative number so must always be positive by definition.  You have not explained how you are seeing positive values so what am I supposed to "check"?

Comment: tried this `unsigned int ii = arc4random();
    NSLog(@"Random:%d",ii);`

Comment: And you are formatting it as signed (`%d`).  I specifically stated in a previous comment to use `%u` with `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` and `NSLog()` is similar in nature.

Comment: @user2526811 So are you going to re-accept my answer, or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `arc4random_uniform()` function. this is the most common random function used.

**arc4random_uniform()** function

> Returns a random number between 0 and the inserted parameter minus 1.
>   For example arc4random_uniform(3) may return 0, 1 or 2 but not 3.

**Example**

```
u_int32_t randomPositiveNo = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1; //to get the range 1 - 5
```

Comment: Why `int`?  `arc4random_uniform()` also returns an unsigned 32-bit integer and the OP will suffer exactly the same issues, so how does this answer solve them?

Comment: @trojanfoe Done!! agree with the return type you suggested, I was concerned about method,so just missed  **u_int32_t**, anyway updated.